# on ARC a UIViewController removed from navigationController.viewControllers，but `dealloc` not call

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, dealloc

on ARC ,

a UIViewController ,named `vc1`, and in navigationController.viewControllers

`vc1` removed from navigationController.viewControllers :

`[navigationController.viewControllers removeObject:vc1];`

but 'dealloc' not called in `vc1`

Comment: Have you made sure that vc1 has no more references?

Comment: You may need to use Instruments to track `retain/release` calls to figure out who is holding on to a reference.

Comment: Is it never called or simply not immediately after the remove?

Comment: @rocky   like: vc0 -> vc1 -> vc2  and removed vc1,so if vc2 comeback ,vc0 will show

Comment: "Yes" is no answer to a Q that contains an "or".